# Error class in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-blade

I want to show the error validation if the input is empty after a submit button. The problem is that the error is always displayed with *black color*. I want it to be with **red**. I am using bootstrap , blade and Laravel in my application.

```
{{ $errors->first('Namespace', '<span class="alert alert-error">:message</span>') }}
            {{ Form::label('Namespace', 'Namespace', array( 'class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label')) }}
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                {{ Form::text('Namespace', Input::old('Namespace'), array( 'class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'namespace')) }}
            </div>
           </div>
```

Please I need your help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use (for Bootstrap 3 which I assume you use because you haven't mentioned about version):

```
{{ $errors->first('Namespace', '<span class="alert alert-danger">:message</span>') }}
```

instead of:

```
{{ $errors->first('Namespace', '<span class="alert alert-error">:message</span>') }}
```

Reference: [Helper classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes)

Comment: This is if he's using Bootstrap v3. [Bootstrap v2 it'd definitely be alert-error](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#alerts). That said, I cant see anything else obviously incorrect. He might just want to make sure he's using the version of bootstrap he this he is, in addition to this fix.

Comment: @charles You are right. OP haven't mentioned about Bootstrap version (he used wrong `Bootstrap` tag when he created his post) but because of no version mentioned I think it's reasonable to assume he uses v3  but I've added info to my answer, thanks